# Findbugs maven scan new code only

Tags: maven, maven-3, findbugs

I am looking for a way to scan only new code of a project with the findbugs plugin for maven but I can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: Why only the new code? Always scan all code...And for what?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such way to scan only new code with the existing Findbugs mavne plugin.
You would need to develop your own that would check your SCM tool and run the check only on given files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Findbugs on either [Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FindBugs+Plugin) or [SonarQube](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-findbugs), you can view a report of the difference between two scans.